# Trying to remove parameter from url using .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove any instance of ?s= from any url its placed into.

This is the current rewrite rule I'm using but it just throws a 500 error any idea why?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=302,QSD]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be on older Apache versions because flag `QSD` is only supported on newer Apache versions `2.4+`. On older Apache versions this will cause `500 internal server error`.

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]
```

`?` in target URL will discard existing query string.